# Does Watson OpenScale support bias checking for regression models?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-openscale

For regression models, the output is not categorical. In this case, will Watson OpenScale also support the bias checking?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, IBM Watson OpenScale supports bias checking for regression models, although it does not support de-biasing or bias mitigation for regression models yet.

Comment: Is there some sample notebook or blog post about that?

Comment: @SumitGoyal Here's a blogpost on bias detection in general: https://medium.com/trusted-ai/bias-detection-in-ibm-watson-openscale-6f37f055a1aa